# Is there a native mechanism for dealing with data duplication in FaunaDb?

Tags: database-design, nosql, faunadb

While investigating for a fresh database, Fauna checks a lot of boxes for me. However, based on the [documentation](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/basics/data_modeling.html#normalization), I wasn't able to infer how/whether Fauna deals with data duplication.

Could somebody share whether data duplication is somehow dealt with by Fauna? Maybe auto-copying based on schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is duplicated in multiple places, then you have to maintain it in both places.

There's nothing automagical about handling relationships in Fauna.  I mean, GraphQL feels like magic sometimes :) but at its core it is just backed by Indexes.  Indexes empower bi-directional relationships between different Collections.  You define the Indexes as the developer (the GraphQL API can help a lot).

I would recommend following along with the [5-minute Quickstart](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/start/index.html) tutorial.  You can create a database with demo data right from the dashboard.  From there you can inspect the different collections and see how the relationships are formed/saved in the actual documents.

Comment: Thanks. Let's please boil it down to an example. Imagine a collection of Chats, each of which have reference to a User. We fetch a page the Chats collection, we know that the most efficient version of that query is if the User data is copied inside each Chat record. But what if Chat only holds a reference to User? Does Fauna offer anything in that regard? Or will the query be N+1? In other words, fetch Chat records page, and then for each Chat, fetch the User.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question from data duplication. You can, in a single query, fetch the details of multiple documents and compose a specific response containing just the fields that you need. This capability is why we claim that our GraphQL API avoids the N+1 problem because we can fulfill all of the requested response fields at once.